# Getting channel subscriptions list by Youtube Data Api

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to order the subscription list of Youtube channels by recently subscribed?

```
youtube
       .subscriptions()
       .list("snippet")
       .setOrder("")// relevance, unread, alphabetical
       .setMaxResults((long) 1000) // it is not affecting, the max limit is 50
       .setMine(true)
       .execute();
```

According to documents, I can only get max 50 items at a time, and I have only three order type parameters **relevance**, **unread**, **alphabetical**.

**But I need to reach the channel I subscribed lastly**. I would be really appreciated it if anybody helps me to handle this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#myRecentSubscribers), you have the following parameter at your disposal:

> **myRecentSubscribers** (boolean)
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request. Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the subscribers of the authenticated user in reverse chronological order (newest first).
>
> Note that this parameter only supports retrieval of the most recent 1000 subscribers to the authenticated user's channel. To retrieve a complete list of subscribers, use the mySubscribers parameter. That parameter, which does not return subscribers in a particular order, does not limit the number of subscribers that can be retrieved.

That is: do insert something like `.setMyRecentSubscribers(true)` in the sequence of setters of your code above. (Also you may remove the `setChannelId` setter call, since, by requiring from you to be authorized to invoke this endpoint, the API already knows the channel to which your call is referring to.)

Note also that the parameter's [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#maxResults) maximum value is `50`. To receive only the most recent subscriber have `.setMaxResults(1)` in the setter sequence above.

---

If your want to obtain the list of all your subscriptions then there's the following parameter:

> **mine** (boolean)
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's subscriptions.

Have `.setMine(true)` (without `.setChannelId`) in your setters sequence.

You will have to invoke repeatedly the API's endpoint to get all of your subscriptions, since this endpoint provides [paginated result sets](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination). Upon obtaining all those subscriptions, sort them by [`snippet.publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet.publishedAt).

If you're only interested to obtain the most recent channel to which to have subscribed, instead of the sort algorithm, is sufficient to use the max algorithm (`O(n)` instead of `O(n log n)`) on the same property.

For an example of how to implement pagination in your code, have a look at some of the [sample code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/07263305b59a7c3275bc7e925f9ce6cabf774022/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/MyUploads.java#L100) provided by Google itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! but I have seen this but it is for the getting subscriber, What I am looking for is the subscriptions. I mean the channels I have recently subscribed not my subscriber list.

Comment: @haliltprkk, if this is the way you wanted it, then your post's text is misleading; for to achive your desired result, I see not other solution than to request the list of all of your subscriptions (`.setMine(true)` without `.setChannelId(...)`) and then sort for the property [`snippet.publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet.publishedAt).

Comment: @haliltprkk: note that this API endpoint produces [paginated result sets](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination); that is that you have to repeatedly call the endpoint passing to it proper [`pageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#pageToken) parameters.

Comment: Hmm, It looks the only way pagination. I wish it would have something like ```.setMyRecentSubscribers(true)```. Thank you so much 

Comment: @haliltprkk: you mean something like `setMyRecentSubscriptions(true)`, right?

Comment: But I still didn't get it. I mean isn't it a parameter I can use to get my subscribers.

Comment: yes exactly! I was looking for smthng like this ```setMyRecentSubscriptions(true)```

Comment: But it looks the API doesn't have

Comment: @haliltprkk: yes, there's the `mine` parameter (see my updated answer above); the API does not have a parameter `myRecentSubscriptions`: that's why your have to get all your subscriptions and sort them yourself to extract the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, you want to check if you are following a specific youtube channel with help of Youtube Data API V3.

For that it is mentioned in the [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22forChannelId%22%3A%22UCP4bf6IHJJQehibu6ai__cg%22%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D) that you can use `forChannelId` parameter.

Also Youtube Data API has a playground to let you see the results of your query. You can simply put a channelId in `forChannelId` field and result will return an empty array if you are not subscribed specified channel or result will return the data of that specified channel if you are subscribed to it.

You can do a simple request from your Java app to get results. In this code example I'm checking if authorized youtube API user is subscribed to `Firebase Youtube Channel` or not.

```
SubscriptionListResponse response = request.setForChannelId("UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw")
        .setMine(true)
        .execute();
```

And response will include details of specified channel in the request you will make. I also share response of the request I shared above.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
  "etag": "zCQ7lTwIBgdyVsQmbymEu-fUgjU",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#subscription",
      "etag": "A-G_B0BnSqn7XtJi7BgHJEk9L3Q",
      "id": "uTEDDg6jpPBwnsim9moHkataEljshwFopudOgIy34nk",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-07-08T14:02:43.789000Z",
        "title": "Google Developers",
        "description": "The Google Developers channel features talks from events, educational series, best practices, tips, and the latest updates across our products and platforms.",
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#channel",
          "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
        },
        "channelId": "UCC77fYySvfP7p-6QGaa-3lw",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Fgp8KFpgQqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Wyh1vV5Up0I/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Fgp8KFpgQqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Wyh1vV5Up0I/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Fgp8KFpgQqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Wyh1vV5Up0I/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```